# ArrayIndexOutofBounds when reading empty cells in csv MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to run MapReduce program for the below data.

[image]

This is my mapper code:

```
@Override
protected void map(Object key, Text value, Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException,InterruptedException {
    String tokens[]=value.toString().split(",");
    if(tokens[6]!=null){
        context.write(new Text(tokens[6]), new IntWritable(1));
    }

}
```

As some of my cell data is empty, when I tried to read the column Carrier_delay I get the error below. Please advise.

```
17/04/13 20:45:29 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1491849620104_0017_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at Test.TestMapper.map(TestMapper.java:22)
    at Test.TestMapper.map(TestMapper.java:17)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
```

[image]

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf,"IP Access");
job.setJarByClass(Test.class);
job.setMapperClass(TestMapper.class);

job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setReducerClass(TestReducer.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line: `if(tokens[6]!=null){`.

The problem is that you want to take the value of tokens[6], and then check if it is null. However, some lines only contain six columns (the seventh is empty), so `tokens`, in those cases, is a six-element array. This means that it contains values from `tokens[0]` to `tokens[5]`. When you try to access `tokens[6]`, you go beyond the size of the array, so you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

The correct way to do what you want is:

```
IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1); //this saves some time ;)
Text keyOutput = new Text(); //the same goes here

@Override
protected void map(Object key, Text value, Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException,InterruptedException {
    String tokens[]=value.toString().split(",");
    if(tokens.length == 7){
        keyOutput.set(tokens[6]);
        context.write(keyOutput, one);
    }

}
```

**More tips:** Judging from your partial code, I guess you want to count the number of times a specific value of carrier delay appears. In that case, you can also use a combiner to speed up the process, as a WordCount program would do. You can also parse the carrier delay as an IntWritable to save time and space.

Answer (score 0):

All the columns are the one shown in the image? if that is the case,remember java arrays are 0 indexed and your columns would range from 0 to 5, so tokens[6] it's out of bounds. Or depending in your necessary logic you could also add a validation in your if:

> if(tokens.length > n && tokens[n]!=null){
>           context.write(new Text(tokens[n]), new IntWritable(1));
>           }

Comment: YEAR,AIRLINE_ID,ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID,ORIGIN,DEST_AIRPORT_ID ,ARR_DELAY CARRIER_DELAY . this is the order

Comment: Again i get the same error after adding the && condition.17/04/13 21:30:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1491849620104_0019_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
 at Test.TestMapper.map(TestMapper.java:22)
 at Test.TestMapper.map(TestMapper.java:17)

Comment: You are using comma as a splitter, but maybe the lines that have empty values, doesnt have the correct number of commas, so the Tokens array has less values, paste an screenshot of the file but open it on a text editor or in the command line with cat so we can check

Comment: mmm,strange, input file seems good, ill do some debugging, comment your current  if statement and instead make your mapper output as key the line itself, and as value the tokens.lenght, something like:
context.write(value, new IntWritable(tokens.length));

Comment: Can i send you the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Carrier delay is 2nd field, so you need to access using token[1] since the array index start with 0. You can also put length check before accessing particular index.  Token[6] is giving error since you have total 6 columns. If you are accessing last field it will be Token[5]  I.e length minus 1.

Comment: YEAR,AIRLINE_ID,ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID,ORIGIN,DEST_AIRPORT_ID ,AR‌​R_DELAY CARRIER_DELA‌​Y . These are my order of columns. I took screnshot of data in the middle

Comment: Can you just cat the file that you are trying to access. and see if you are getting separator for all 7 fields. If some of the  fields are blanks the separator comma should still be present and then you can put length check. Better if you can paste top 10 records from.hdfs file.

Comment: thiyagarajans-MacBook-Pro:Dataset nirmal$ cat ONTIME.csv|head -10|column -s -t
"YEAR","AIRLINE_ID","ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID","ORIGIN","DEST_AIRPORT_ID","ARR_DELAY","CARRIER_DELAY","WEATHER_DELAY","NAS_DELAY","SECURITY_DELAY","LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY",
2016,19805,11298,"DFW",11433,-6.00,,,,,,
2016,19805,11298,"DFW",11433,-12.00,,,,,,
2016,19805,11298,"DFW",11433,7.00,,,,,,
2016,19805,11298,"DFW",11433,-5.00,,,,,,
2016,19805,11298,"DFW",11433,113.00,0.00,0.00,47.00,0.00,66.00,

Comment: Can you paste the driver code snippet. Are you using default input format or keyvalueinputformat